# Rav Hai Gaon Visiting Italy

Tags: geonim, italy

I’d like to know if Rav Hai Gaon actually visited Italy in the end years of his life. I remember reading that somewhere in the Mordecai it is written. Are there any other sources that mention his physical journey to Europe?

Comment: FYI it's the Mordechai on Shabbat 118a: "וטעם זה שמע ר"י בר יהודה בעיר רומי מפי רב האי גאון". [Apparently](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94) this is Rabbi Yitzchak of Mainz, one of Rashi's rabbis. Naturally, there are disagreements on whether Rav Hai actually came to Rome or not. The Mordechai appears to be the only source of this tradition.

Comment: Can you cite some of these disagreements from other Jewish texts? Thanks.

Comment: I thought I remembered seeing such sources at the time, but I'm not seeing any now, so I guess I was wrong.